# Sort documents on the basis of document property using cts:search

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have document properties for each document -

```
<prop:properties xmlns:prop="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property">
  <prop:last-modified>2017-04-12T04:55:57Z</prop:last-modified>
</prop:properties>
```

Now I want to sort my search results using `prop:last-modified`. One way which I got to know is to [use a loop](http://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2010-August/006123.html). But this loop will have an impact on the performance of the query.

Is there any other way to get the search results with-in MarkLogic only?

Answer (score 2):

`cts:search()` allows an order-specification as one of its options, and you can use [cts:index-order](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order) to set that option.

So if you're searching on `prop:last-modified`, it's not far to go from the example in the [cts:search documentation](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search?q=cts:search&v=8.0&api=true). Unfortunately, this sorting option gets ignored (may be a bug).

```
cts:search(fn:doc(), "hello",
("unfiltered",
 cts:index-order(
     cts:element-reference(
         xs:QName("prop:last-modified")),
         "descending")))[1 to 10]
```

Note that you need an element range index defined for `prop:last-modified`.

Your workaround appears to be the most efficient and straightforward way to handle this. Pull the search results into a FLWOR statement, and sort them using plain old `order by`:

```
for $r in cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:true-query())
order by $r/property::prop:last-modified descending
return $r/property::prop:last-modified
```

Comment: Will this work on document properties? I tried it, but it is not working. It looks like sorting on document and not document properties.

Comment: Do you have an element-range index defined for the document property? You need to set that up the same way you would a document element-range index.

Comment: I have a element-range-index defined with
uri - http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property
localname - last-modified
type - dateTime

Comment: Sounds like the index is set up correctly (as longs as you include the "http://" at the beginning of the namespace). What do you mean by "sorting on document and not document properties" and "not working"? Without knowing the actual `cts:search` call or the output, it's hard for me to offer more specific troubleshooting advice. Are you getting an error or are you getting documents back in the wrong order?

Comment: I am using this query - 

declare namespace prop = "marklogic.com/xdmp/property";; cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:true-query(), ((), (cts:index-order( cts:element-reference( xs:QName("prop:last-modified")), "ascending"))))[1 to 10] 

I am getting same results in the same sequence for both ascending and descending. That's why I am assuming that sorting is not working properly

Comment: You're right, it looks like the index-order option is getting ignored.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `declare namespace prop = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property";`  Also, can you confirm that you changed your element-range-index to use `http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property` for the namespace?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that was getting screwed up by the comment formatting. Even with the correct namespace, the option gets ignored.

Comment: The namespace is being passed in the way suggested by @SamMefford. It is getting screwed in comment formatting.

Comment: Because the prop:last-modified element is in the properties fragment I'd be surprised if you can use cts:index-order for this.

Comment: @hunterhacker Then what is the workaround if we want to sort documents using some element in the property fragment. Currently I am using a flowr to sort documents on the basis of property -

`let $search := cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:true-query())
return
  for $r in $search
  order by $r/property::prop:committed-on descending
  return $r/property::prop:committed-on`

Comment: The workaround of the flwor sorting by the xpath will work but requires a disk IO per doc in the search result set. It's only viable if your result sets are quite small. I don't know a way to do this efficiently unless the last modified time gets put in the document fragment itself.