# Sorting /v1/search results

Tags: marklogic

Is there a way to force an ordering on the results of a `/v1/search` request?  It seems that cts:search allows you to order the results based on a range index, but `/v1/search` does not have a direct way to specify the same options, and stored query options don't seem to support index ordering in the same way.

My question is not related to `cts:search`, however.  I'm looking for a usage example of the `/v1/search` ReST endpoint with query options that specify sorting.  As far as my research has gone, [`/v1/search`](https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/REST/GET/v1/search) has an optional `options` query parameter which specifies named search options that can be defined using [`/v1/config/query`](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/config/query/['default'-or-name]).  At this point, I feel lost in the maze of the documentation and what I'm really looking for is an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort documents on the basis of document property using cts:search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463632/sort-documents-on-the-basis-of-document-property-using-ctssearch)

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at the [`sort-order`](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_44212) query option? It is the equivalent of a `cts:order` specification on `cts:search`.

I think you need at least MarkLogic 9.0-3 to get the full slate of sort-order choices. See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_44212.